# Clearing Bot State Data from Chain.From().Do() returns "Sorry, my bot code is having an issue"

Tags: botframework

Trying to Set User Data in this code keeping returning "Sorry, my bot code is having an issue"

```
internal static IDialog<SandwichOrder> MakeRootDialog()
    {
        return Chain.From(() => FormDialog.FromForm(SandwichOrder.BuildForm))
            .Do(async (context, order) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    var activity = context.Activity;
                    var channelId = activity.ChannelId;
                    var fromId = activity.From.Id;
                    var stateClient = activity.GetStateClient();
                    **var userData = await stateClient.BotState.GetUserDataAsync(activity.ChannelId, activity.From.Id);
                    // modify a property within user data 
                    userData.SetProperty<string>("SerialNumber", "");
                    // save updated user data
                    await stateClient.BotState.SetUserDataAsync(activity.ChannelId, activity.From.Id, userData);**

                    var completed = await order;
                    // Actually process the sandwich order...
                    await context.PostAsync("Defect data submitted!");

                }
                catch (HttpOperationException err)
                {
                    // handle error with HTTP status code 412 Precondition Failed
                }
                catch (FormCanceledException<SandwichOrder> e)
                {
                    string reply;
                    if (e.InnerException == null)
                    {

                        reply = $"You quit on {e.Last}--maybe you can finish next time!";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        reply = "Sorry, I've had a short circuit.  Please try again.";
                    }

                    await context.PostAsync(reply);
                }
            });
    }
```

It's actually working and clearing the Property but I don't want to see that error message anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using activity.GetStateClient(), use the dialog context's methods to manipulate state inside of the dialog's methods.

What is happening is the state is deserialized when the dialog is loaded, and auto-saved when the dialog finishes.  If you create a state client manually within the dialog, and manipulate state, there is a conflict when the auto-save occurs.

---

Edit:
This functions as expected.

In the controller:

```
var stateClient = activity.GetStateClient(); // this is the default state client (recommended only for prototyping)

var userData = await stateClient.BotState.GetUserDataAsync(activity.ChannelId, activity.From.Id);
userData.SetProperty<string>("SerialNumber", "test serial number");
await stateClient.BotState.SetUserDataAsync(activity.ChannelId, activity.From.Id, userData);

await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, TestForm.MakeRootDialog);

userData = await stateClient.BotState.GetUserDataAsync(activity.ChannelId, activity.From.Id); //after the form completes, SerialNumber is empty here
```

The form:

```
public class TestForm
{
    internal static IDialog<SandwichOrder> MakeRootDialog()
    {
        return Chain.From(() => FormDialog.FromForm(SandwichOrder.BuildForm))
            .Do(async (context, order) =>
            {

                    var serialNumber = context.UserData.GetValue<string>("SerialNumber");

                    context.UserData.SetValue("SerialNumber", "");

                    var completed = await order;
                    // Actually process the sandwich order...
                    await context.PostAsync("Defect data submitted!");                    
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Eric,  I'm actually setting state before I call static IDialog<SandwichOrder> MakeRootDialog() in the MessageController code.  I have to do this because I need to read a Bar Code attachment (to extract the serial number) first since the Form Dialog does not support attachments.    Calling context.ConversationData.SetValue("SerialNumber", "");  does not work

Comment: Do you have a custom state client? or are you using the Azure Extensions? https://blog.botframework.com/2017/07/18/saving-state-azure-extensions/

Comment: I just tested: context.ConversationData.SetValue("SerialNumber", "") what about that does not work for your scenario?

Comment: I am not using any custom state client or Azure Extensions....     Before calling MakeRootDialog, in the MessageController, I'm asking the user to provide a BarCode image (or to type it in manually).  Then I save the serial number in the User Data state outside of the dialog context... then I kick off the Dialog to grab other info that's required from the user via the form interaction.  I need to clear this state before the next go around.  I'll repeat that calling context.ConversationData.SetValue("SerialNumber", ""); does not work.  The Serial Number is still in the User Data state

Comment: Eric... its working now 
IMPROPER Code:
context.ConversationData.SetValue("SerialNumber", "");

CORRECT code (as you suggested):
context.UserData.SetValue("SerialNumber", "");